# What am i missing to create socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to create a client/server by C, this is my first C programing learning and I want to do connection by localhost only, not by internet , what am i missing. How do i fix it and get my server up and running, and what should i type to get my client connect to my server.

I need to create a server that can send and receive with client. Sorry i am new to C programing, just on learning phase, do pardon my lack of experience and would love to learn from experts here.

Below is my code in main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
int serverFd;
int clientFd;
struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;

cout << "" << endl;
cout << "Running server program 'css' ...... " << endl;
cout << "" << endl;


// SOCKET CREATION PART - SERVER
serverFd = socket (AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* Set domain type */
serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL; 

/* Set name */ 
strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path, "Server"); 

/* Remove file if it already exists */ 
unlink ("Server"); 

/* Create file */
bind (serverFd, serverSockAddrPtr, serverLen);

// SOCKET CREATION END - SERVER

return 0;
}
```

Error I get:

```
CountryServer.c:39:17: error: ‘serverSockAddrPtr’ was not declared in this scope
CountryServer.c:39:36: error: ‘serverLen’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: The header files? Also, please include the lines of error, identifying them with a comment or something.

Comment: The header files as @Shahbaz mentioned. Please see [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html) for more information on socket programming using C.

Comment: Apparently you forgot to include some header files, the error indicates that struct sockaddr_un serverAddress is interpreted the declaration of a new struct type. Also, don't use strcpy, use strncpy instead.

Comment: I still got some error after adding the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the errors say, you're using names (`serverSockAddrPtr` and `serverLen`) which you haven't declared. What you want are the *address* and *size* of the `serverAddress` structure:

```
bind (serverFd, 
      reinterpret_cast<sockaddr const *>(&serverAddress), 
      sizeof serverAddress);
```

Comment: I get this error 

root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/shell_assn2# g++ -o CountryServer CountryServer.c
CountryServer.c: In function ‘int main()’:
CountryServer.c:44:43: error: cannot convert ‘sockaddr_un*’ to ‘const sockaddr*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int bind(int, const sockaddr*, socklen_t)’

Comment: @BaokyANewProgramer: Oh yes, you'll need a cast. See my update (or, better still, the [manpage for bind](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind), although the example there is in C rather than C++).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some headers.

According to [this manpage](http://basepath.com/aup/ex/structsockaddr__un.html), `struct sockaddr_un` is in `sys/un.h`.